# set qstring to qprocess properly

Tags: c++, qt, ros

I am trying to set a QString to Qprocess to execute it in Qt.
My problem is that I can't get it working although it seems fine from the [QProcess Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).
I wanted to do this in a pushbutton press, so my code looked at first like the following (thumbs up, the process is a ROS Command):

```
void Viatic_Interface::gazebo_launch_world()
{
    QString program = "roslaunch";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << " wifibot_gazebo " << ui->txt_world->text();

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
    QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
    myProcess->setProcessEnvironment(env);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
    myProcess->waitForStarted(-1);
}
```

and that didn't work. It looks like sth is going in getting the QString from the LineEdit.
Just to check if my command works, I tried to set the command as a one line command and it worked :

```
void Viatic_Interface::gazebo_launch_world()
{
    QString program = "roslaunch wifibot_gazebo wifibot_gazebo.launch";

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
    QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
    myProcess->setProcessEnvironment(env);
    myProcess->start(program);
    myProcess->waitForStarted(-1);
}
```

Am I missing something ??

Comment: Try without the trailing spaces in `" wifibot_gazebo “`, i.e. with `“wifibot_gazebo”`. When passing a QStringList, the arguments are separated by spaces automatically and adding more spaces to arguments leads to quoting.

Comment: Try with the full file-path of the "roslaunch" program

Comment: hi, @Frank i tried without the spaces as '"wifibot_gazebo"' and it didn't work either. Felix, even without the path of  '"roslaunch"', it worked for the second code. So I don't think it's a path problem. Thx

Comment: Check with `"roslaunch" << "wifibot_gazebo"  << "wifibot_gazebo.launch"`. Then check if it works with your line edit (maybe there's trailing whitespace in there?). Check if it failed during the run or if it doesn't start at all (check the return code of waitForStarted, if it starts, check if the process output (stdout and stderr) contains anything useful and what the exitCode()/errorString() etc. return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

This was solved by removing the spaces and adding a QString cast, like this :

```
void Viatic_Interface::gazebo_launch_world()
{
    QString program = "roslaunch";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "wifibot_gazebo" << (QString)ui->txt_world->text();

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
    QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
    myProcess->setProcessEnvironment(env);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
    myProcess->waitForStarted(-1);
}
```

found no explanation why...

Thanks for the help anyway !

Cheers,